# Adding hyperlink to a button on my designed image?

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm a designer with little to no HTML experience and basically, what I did was, I designed a promotion code letter to be sent out to my clients and on the letter, there is a button that says "Shop Now". I want this button to be clickable by the user, so that when they click it, they get directed to our company's website.I was wondering how would I go about doing that? Do I need to find a developer to do this job or can I do it myself? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Well, a hyperlink and a button are generally 2 different things.  But in the button HTML you would add an "onclick:" event, and then it activates a specific code function that you want it to do.  OR, you could wrap that button in an anchor tag (hyperlink) with the href property directed to the company's site.

Comment: This site is for questions involving code. If you have any code that you're stuck on, edit your question to include it. Otherwise, please remove your question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

simply add `<a href=""></a>` around the html from the button.
between the `""` you set the link to where the button

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="http://www.thewebsite.com">Shop Now</a>
```

the easy way is this an then you give him a bit style in the css with border,color,...